# How to change the entry point name in a simple assembly program?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly, masm

Having such a simple Win32 assembly program

```
.386
.model flat, c
option casemap :none

;includelib C:\Users\Darek\Dev\VC\lib\libcmt.lib
;includelib C:\Users\Darek\Dev\VC\lib\legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

EXTERN printf :PROC ; declare printf

.data
    HelloWorld db "Hello j World!:-)", 0

.code
main PROC
  push offset HelloWorld
  call printf
    add esp, 4
  ret
main ENDP
END
```

I'd like to change the *entry point* name from the standard `main` to say *my_start*, so I've changed the name of the main function to `my_start`

```
...
my_start PROC
...
my_start ENDP
...
```

and then linked like below

```
link /ENTRY:my_start /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE HelloWorld.obj libcmt.lib
```

but getting the linker error:

> undefined external symbol _main called in _mainCRTStartup
> Why does the linker ingres the ENTRY option?
> What I'm doing wrong and what to do to get it working?

P.S.

I'm using the `ml` and `link` provided with my `MSVC 2019`

Comment: The actual entry point is in the C library, which then calls your `main`.

Comment: @Jester Sorry, but can You explain me more?

Comment: Try using "msvcrt.lib" instead of "libcmt.lib". I tried your code adding the following line near the top: `includelib "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\msvcrt.lib"` (no need to add any extra files to the linker command) and it worked.

Comment: @AdrianMole. Ok thx changing from `libcmt` to `msvcrt `did the work BUT can You be so nice and explain me why the solution with the `libcmt` IS'T work? Doesn't the `libcmt` accept entry point option?

Answer (score 1):

C requires your main program to be called `main`. That's a restriction imposed by C, not the hardware itself. I've only ever used UASM and x86-16, so I'm not familiar with Win32 syntax, but you might be able to try this:

```
my_start equ main
```

(Assuming Win32 has an `equ` directive that is.)

Comment: Win32 is a target platform, not an assembler.  In this case the assembler is MASM, but other assemblers (like NASM or FASM) can also target Win32 object files or executables.  In NASM, `equ` definitely only works with numbers or already-defined symbols, not a text-substitution like CPP macros.  In FASM it is a text substitution.  Not sure about MASM.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not used to using PROC for my subroutines (I only discovered it existed recently) so I'm not entirely familiar with what you can and can't do with it.

Comment: That's irrelevant for what you can do with `equ` in MASM, but ok.

Comment: I thought maybe you could say something like ```PROC main``` and then have ```my_start equ main``` so that in your code you could use ```CALL main``` or ```CALL myStart``` interchangably.

Comment: Oh, yeah you can possibly do that (if you're linking the CRT code that wants to call main, instead of actually making this the process entry point.)  But the code in the question has `proc my_start` not `proc main`, so your `equ` is backwards.  (Although IDK if it would work the other way around, to define `main` as a synonym / alias that's actually visible for linking.)